# React Array State Filter Clears the Array

Tags: reactjs

When i press the delete button, i want to update the itemListState in my App.js. But it deletes everything in the state. What is wrong in my "itemDeleteHandler" function? Index number and the id matches. Filter function should do the work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserInput from './components/UserInput';
import ItemList from './components/ItemList';

const App = (props) => {
  const [itemListState, setItemListState] = useState([]);

  const userInputHandler = (newUserInput) => {
    setItemListState((prevState) => ([
      ...prevState, newUserInput
    ]))
  }

  const itemDeleteHandler = (id) => {
    setItemListState((prevState) => ([
      prevState.filter((item, index) => {
        // DELETES ALL THE ITEMS WHY?
        return parseInt(id) !== index;
      })
    ]));
    console.log(itemListState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <UserInput onAddUserInput={userInputHandler} />
      <hr className="item__hr" />
      <ItemList userInputProp={itemListState} onDeleteItem={itemDeleteHandler} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extraneous pair of brackets in the delete handler, so you end up with a list with 1 item containing the rest.

You'll want

```
const itemDeleteHandler = (id) => {
  setItemListState((prevState) =>
    prevState.filter(
      (item, index) =>
        parseInt(id) !== index,
    ),
  );
};
```

instead.

Comment: Might be a forgotten spread operator since the other handler uses the spread operator as well.

Comment: The other handler uses spread to append an item to the array.

Comment: AKX it worked. Thank you a lot. I dont quite understand the diference. Is it an arrow function thing or is it about react? Is there like a documentation or article about this that i can read?

Comment: The difference is `[[foo, bar]]` and `[foo, bar]`...